Cannot remove an Item from a C# list
I have a C# list of students. I cannot remove Item based on Id.
Program.cs
static void RemoveStudent(StudentManager studentManager)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Which student? Insert ID:");
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(id);
    studentManager.RemoveStudent(1);
}

How student class looks like:
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Major { get; set; }
}

How StudentManagerClass looks like:
public class StudentManager
{
    private List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

    public void RemoveStudent(int id)
    {
        students.RemoveAt(id);
    }
   
    //...
}

Program exits without any prompt when trying to remove the element.

Note that RemoveAt removes the student at that index, without respect for ids.

students.RemoveAll(student => student.Id == id);

List.RemoveAt is documented to do the following:

Removes the element at the specified index of the List.

(emphasis in mine)
In your case id is not the index of the element (which is a sequential numbering of the elements in the list starting at 0), but rather the value of a specific property of it.
In order to remove an element by a given property, you can use List.RemoveAll which:

Removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate.

In this predicate you can compare the Id property to the one you want to remove:
//----------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--
students.RemoveAll(student => student.Id == id);


@JohnathanBarclay thanks for the edit. Id is indeed a property here, not a field.

The issue in your code is that you are using the RemoveAt method, which removes a student based on the index, not the Id property. Additionally, RemoveAt expects a zero-based index, so if the id doesn't match the index, it will cause an exception.
To fix this, you should find the student by their Id property and then remove them from the list. Tell me if that worked for you :))
